# Plotting from a 2D Array Using a Loop

Tags: arrays, r, plot

This seems like a trivial problem, though I've been hitting myself over the head with it for too long.

This doesn't even plot just the (0,0) -- I can't seem to find much about plotting from arrays -- rather just matrix plots (and only columns at that).

The data is properly in these arrays, I just need to make plots! Doesn't seem so complicated. I don't even need separate colors for the different sets...just all one big scatter plot.

Any suggestions?

```
pdf(mypath)
# Plot first point
plot(0,0, col = "blue", type = "n", xlab="PES", ylab=""%eff")

#Loop to Plot remaining points
for(rows in 1:nrowX)
{
   for(cols in 1:ncolX)
   {
      points(X[rows,cols],Y[rows,cols], col = "blue", type = "p")
   }
}
dev.off
```

I have also tried using `plot.new()` to have an empty plot...but no such luck.

---

SOLUTION!!

Turns out I'm just a fool. Code is acurate and the suggestions below do indeed work.

R happened to be open in another tab and since it was open, never let go of the plot (why? I don't know). As soon as it was closed, the plot appeared. Now I can get my plot again and again...

Thanks to everyone who tried helping a problem that wasn't a problem!

I like this place already!

Answer (score 0):

Your initial plot will set up the coordinates, but since you only give it one point it does not know how much room to leave around the 0,0 point (so it does not leave very much).  I expect that the rest of your points fall outside of that range which is why they don't show up on the plot (you can use `par("usr")` to see what the extents are).

When you create the initial plot you should include `xlim` and `ylim` arguments so that the plot includes the area where the new points will be added, something like:

```
plot(0,0, type='n', xlim=range(X), ylim=range(Y))
```

You may also be interested in the `matplot` function which will take a matrix as either or both the x and/or y argument and plot accordingly.

**Edit**

The following works for me:

```
X <- matrix( runif(390), nrow=10 )
Y <- matrix( rnorm(390), nrow=10 )


plot(0,0, col = "blue", type = "n", xlab="PES", ylab="%eff",
    xlim=range(X), ylim=range(Y))

#Loop to Plot remaining points
for(rows in 1:nrow(X))
{
   for(cols in 1:ncol(X))
   {
      points(X[rows,cols],Y[rows,cols], col = "blue", type = "p")
   }
}
```

I did remove an extra `"` from the `ylab`, was that your problem?

But

```
plot(X,Y)
```

also worked without the looping.

Check with just the console to see if it works before worrying about sending to a pdf file.  If this has not fixed it yet, we still need more details.

Comment: No such luck with adding limits -- it's still not even plotting the original first plot. It gives me a invalid file. Matplot didn't seem to work in earlier attempts. Though I am confused why what I have does not simply work. It's pretty simple and straight forward.

Comment: @BluePanda, it is hard for us to diagnose what is going on without a reproducible example.  Can you provide us with `mypath`, `X`, and `Y` (using `dput`) or code that generates random data of the correct shape?

Comment: I understand. mypath is just a path for it to save to (plots to output.pdf for example). You can make that whatever you like. As for X and Y -- they are both 10x39 arrays; but can vary in size based on the data. Regardless they are going to both be the same size.

Comment: I see your example -- it's really not much different than my code. The only real difference being that you are using matrix form for the arrays where I actually have an 2D array storing the data -- not a matrix.

Answer (score 0):

When you set `type = "n"`, the plot function will not plot anything at all. It is used to set up a basis for the rest of the plot (like axis labels, limits etc). That is why the first point at (0, 0) does not show up.

The rest of the points are probably outside the range. Use `xlim` and `ylim` to set up the ranges properly. I'm going to assume `X` and `Y` have the same size and dimension. Try this:

```
pdf(mypath)

# Set up the plot
plot(0, type="n", xlab="PES", ylab="%eff", xlim=range(X), ylim=range(y))

# Now plot
points(X,Y, col="blue")

dev.off
```

Of course you could let the `plot` function take care of the limits for you:

```
pdf(mypath)
plot(X, Y, xlab="PES", ylab="%eff")
dev.off()
```